# What are Windows clipboard CF_ formats like -16230, -15835, -15834, etc?

Tags: c#, winapi

All formats I could find were [these in the MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats). When trying to implement file drag and drop (from my application to Windows' File Explorer), I get lots of `GetData` requests for `cfFormat` values like -16230, -15835, -15834, but I do not know what they are.

[Full Log when I tried to drag a file name from my app to File Explorer using the `DoDragDrop` function.]

```
Mouse Down
EnumFormatEtc
EnumFormatEtc::Next(1)
EnumFormatEtc::Next(1)
EnumFormatEtc::Reset
EnumFormatEtc::Next(1)
EnumFormatEtc::Next(1)
QueryGetData(cf = 15, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
GetData(cf = -16230, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15835, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15834, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15833, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15832, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15832, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16207, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16215, ty = TYMED_ISTREAM, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15797, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
QueryGetData(cf = -16230, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
SetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
GetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15832, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16207, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15797, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
SetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
GetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15832, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16207, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15797, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
SetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
GetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15832, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16207, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15797, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
SetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
GetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15832, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16207, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15797, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
SetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
GetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15832, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16207, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15797, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
SetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
GetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15832, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16207, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15797, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
SetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
GetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15832, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16207, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15797, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
SetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
GetData(cf = -16206, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -15832, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
GetData(cf = -16207, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
Returning null.
SetData(cf = -16207, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
SetData(cf = -15864, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
SetData(cf = -15835, ty = TYMED_HGLOBAL, asp = DVASPECT_CONTENT)
```

[Relevant Code]

```
public void GetData(ref FORMATETC format, out STGMEDIUM medium)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"GetData(cf = {format.cfFormat}, ty = {format.tymed}, asp = {format.dwAspect})");

    if (format.cfFormat == CF_HDROP &&
        (format.tymed & TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL) == TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Returning file drop data");
        var mem = CreateDropFiles(new[] { file1, file2 
        });

        medium = new STGMEDIUM();
        medium.tymed = TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL;
        medium.unionmember = mem;
        medium.pUnkForRelease = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Returning null.");
        medium = new STGMEDIUM();
        medium.tymed = TYMED.TYMED_NULL;
        medium.unionmember = IntPtr.Zero;
        medium.pUnkForRelease = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}

public int QueryGetData(ref FORMATETC format)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"QueryGetData(cf = {format.cfFormat}, ty = {format.tymed}, asp = {format.dwAspect})");
    if (format.cfFormat == CF_HDROP)
        return S_OK;
    else
        return DV_E_FORMATETC;
}

public void SetData(ref FORMATETC formatIn, ref STGMEDIUM medium, bool release)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"SetData(cf = {formatIn.cfFormat}, ty = {formatIn.tymed}, asp = {formatIn.dwAspect})");
}
```

I used the `FORMATETC` in `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes`, which has `public short cfFormat`, but in Windows' API, it is defined as `CLIPFORMAT cfFormat`, which in turn `typedef WORD CLIPFORMAT`, which in turn `typedef unsigned short WORD;`. So, to me the type is mismatching (short and unsigned short). I am not sure if it matters or not.

Comment: Try calling `GetClipboardFormatName()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you're right to state that you have a type mismatch.  The Clipboard Formats are unsigned.  Let's take one value:

`-16230`

Treated as a signed WORD, this is

`0xC09A`

This isn't too surprising.  The documentation for [RegisterClipboardFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclipboardformata) says this:

> Registered clipboard formats are identified by values in the range 0xC000 through 0xFFFF.

The other possible values are mentioned in the documentation for [the clipboard formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats#registered-clipboard-formats):

> An application can identify a private clipboard format by defining a value in the range CF_PRIVATEFIRST through CF_PRIVATELAST

`CF_PRIVATEFIRST` through `CF_PRIVATELAST` map to `0x0200` to `0x02FF`.

Clearly you're seeing one of the registered clipboard formats.  To see what type it really is, you need to call `GetClipboardFormatName` when you encounter the value.  It could change from time to time, since these are values that are handed out as different components register their clipboard formats.